# Reusing PHPUnit Data Provider

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm not sure if I can do that, and if I should do that too. I'm writing some tests that could have the same data provider (IP addresses or integers).

```
class LocalIpAddressTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    protected $parser = null;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->parser = new ApacheLogParser();
        $this->parser->setFormat('%A');
    }

    protected function tearDown()
    {
        $this->parser = null;
    }

    /**
     * @dataProvider successProvider
     */
    public function testSuccess($line)
    {
        $entry = $this->parser->parse($line);
        $this->assertEquals($line, $entry->localIp);
    }

    /**
     * @expectedException \Kassner\ApacheLogParser\FormatException
     * @dataProvider invalidProvider
     */
    public function testInvalid($line)
    {
        $this->parser->parse($line);
    }

    public function successProvider()
    {
        return array(
            array('192.168.1.1'),
            array('192.168.001.01'),
            array('172.16.0.1'),
            array('192.168.0.255'),
            array('8.8.8.8'),
            // not sure about those 2. They are valid ip-format, but can't be assigned as server address
            array('0.0.0.0'),
            array('255.255.255.255'),
        );
    }

    public function invalidProvider()
    {
        return array(
            // over 255
            array('192.168.1.256'),
            array('256.256.256.256'),
            array('321.432.543.654'),
            // incomplete
            array('192.168.1.'),
            array('192.168.1'),
            array('192.168.'),
            array('192.168'),
            array('192.'),
            array('192'),
            array(''),
            // malformed
            array('1921.68.1.1'),
            array('192.681.1.'),
            array('.1921.68.1.1'),
            array('....'),
            array('1.9.2.'),
            array('192.168.1.1/24'),
            // letters (it' not supporting IPv6 yet...)
            array('abc'),
            array('192.168.1.x'),
            array('insert-ip-address-here'),
            array('a.b.c.d'),
        );
    }

}
```

Then, I have to test when I use `$this->parser->setFormat('%a')`, that also receives IP Address as an argument. In this case, I'm duplicating all the code just to change one single line. Is it supposed to be that way? Have some way to reuse these Data Providers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be able to do that without any problems as long as the dataprovider method is part of the same class. You could include it in a abstract testcase from which your testcase inherits or make use of traits as of php 5.4+.

Comment: The inherited class could not be another test? When my `RemoteIpAddressTest` extends `LocalIpAddressTest` I have to copy all methods (except the providers) to get things working. Or should I create a `IpAddressProvider` just for provider's implementation and both tests extend from it?

Comment: I don't understand the usecase exactly. You wan't to test different parsers (ApacheLogParser, MyOtherParser) with the same ipAddress providers (invalid and success)? Or you want to test ApacheLogParser with different datasets, which is what your comment indicates?

Comment: You can also use the @depends (http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html) syntax to have references passed from test to test, such as a populated array(). etc...

Comment: @BramGerritsen, I need to test ApacheLogParser several times, each one with a different ->setFormat() call. Sometimes, some formats expects the same load (%a and %A expects IP Address, but those does not mean the same thing on a log). Let me know if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: @StevenScott, a test not necessarily depends from another, just the load of some tests are the same. My concern is about duplicated code on tests namespace, which I'm not pretty sure if it's a big deal.

Comment: @RafaelKassner , then the depends is not needed as you indicated. I think then that @ Bram's solution will work.

Comment: @RafaelKassner, you could eighter test for both %a and %A in the same testcase. You only have a few lines of testcode, so I don't see any point in extracting those to seperate classes. Or you could go for the solution as stated in my answer. You have to create a `IpAddressFormatTestCase` which contains the dataproviders and let both Locale and Remote extend from that. But the cleanest solution imo is to provide the dataproviders as a trait, which will allow for horizontal reusability (inheritance you can only extends ONE other class). You could easily use the trait in non parser tests as well.

Comment: Thanks, I created a base class and made tests extend it. I'm not sure about dropping PHP 5.3 support yet.